# Obtaining a count of grouping, but still displaying all records in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table of race results in MySQL, each rider will have a row entry with some common data - date, location, race, groups, but also unique data like rider_id, finishing times, position etc. What I'm trying to achieve is to add a column to that row counting the number of racers per group. I can easily display the count per date/race/group, but I still have to return all the rows within each group

It's trivial to produce the count I need..  no so much to still display all individual records.

```
SELECT 
    date, race, grade, rider_id, position
    COUNT(*)  AS participants
FROM
    wpsa_results
GROUP BY date, race, grade
```

```
This is the result, but I need ALL 4 records from A, ALL 8 from B etc showing each rider

Date        Race    Grade   RiderID Position Count
2019-11-03  GSR     A       5755    1        4
2019-11-03  GSR     B       4697    1        8
2019-11-03  GSR     C       7661    1        10
2019-11-03  GSR     D       4743    1        8
2019-11-03  GSR     E       2400    1        6
2019-11-03  GSR     F       4295    1        9
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the count into a sub query

```
SELECT 
    w.date, w.race, w.grade, w.rider_id, w.position,
    (select COUNT(*) from wpsa_results w2 where w2.date = w.date and w2.race = w.race and w2.grade = w.grade) AS participants
FROM wpsa_results w;
```

or create a virtual table and join

```
SELECT 
    w.date, w.race, w.grade, w.rider_id, w.position
FROM wpsa_results w
join (select w.date, w.race, w.grade, count(*) as cnt group by w.date, w.race, w.grade) w2
        on w2.date = w.date and w2.race = w.race and w2.grade = w.grade
```

Comment: @BaronVonThierry So, like everything.